# Java regex to extract text sequences across multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, text, sequence

Given an excerpt of text like

```
Preface (optional, up to multiple lines)
Main : sequence1
   sequence2
   sequence3
   sequence4
Epilogue (optional, up to multiple lines)
```

which `Java` regular expression could be used to extract all the sequences (i.e. `sequence1`, `sequence2`, `sequence3`, `sequence4` above)? For example, a `Matcher.find()` loop?

Each "sequence" is preceded by and may also contain 0 or more white spaces (including tabs).

The following regex

```
(?m).*Main(?:[ |t]+:(?:[ |t]+(\S+)[\r\n])+
```

only yields the first sequence (`sequence1`).

Comment: Does it mean you need to get multiple matches of the non-whitespace chunks that have some horizontal whitespaces on the subsequent lines after `Main :`?

Comment: Use [`String p = "(?m)(?:\\G(?!\\A)[^\\S\r\n]+|^Main\\s*:\\s*)(\\S+)\r?\n?";`](https://regex101.com/r/P1od0v/1)

Comment: One match per line. Your regex works, thanks and +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/P1od0v/1):

```
(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)[^\S\r\n]+|^Main\s*:\s*)(\S+)\r?\n?
```

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `(?:\G(?!\A)[^\S\r\n]+|^Main\s*:\s*)`  - either of the two:

  - `\G(?!\A)[^\S\r\n]+` - end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) and then 1+ horizontal whitespaces (`[^\S\r\n]+`, can be replaced with `[\p{Zs}\t]+` or  `[\s&&[^\r\n]]+`)
  - `|` - or
  - `^Main\s*:\s*` - start of a line, `Main`, 0+ whitespaces, `:`,  0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `\r?\n?`  - an optional CR and an optional LF.

See the Java code below:

```
String p = "(?m)(?:\\G(?!\\A)[^\\S\r\n]+|^Main\\s*:\\s*)(\\S+)\r?\n?";
String s = "Preface (optional, up to multiple lines)...\nMain : sequence1\n   sequence2\n   sequence3\n   sequence4\nEpilogue (optional, up to multiple lines)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(p).matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: See [a Java demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcEVDU3VXUjk0QWM).

Comment: It works, thanks. Ideally, I would like something without anchors (\G or \A), but still it does the job. Maybe a simpler version exists. :-)

Comment: With 1 regex pass, this is the only way.

Comment: It is definitely an elegant one. If no simpler version appears, it will also become the selected answer. Thanks again. :-)